# How to loop a queue of songs in AVQueuePlayer even when device is locked?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I already have a looping implementation, and it works when the device is open. I listen for the AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification and handle the looping in that Callback. But as soon as the device is locked, it the AVQueuePlayer does not play. Is this somehow related to iOS backgrounding and how apps function when backgrounded?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Apple does not allow apps to run in background. If you want to play a song in background, you should set the `Required Background Modes` property in the application's `Info.plist`.

> Audio - Music players and other applications that work with audio
>   content may be registered to continue playing audio even when the app
>   is no longer in the foreground. If an app in this category attempts to
>   do anything other than play audio or download while in the background,
>   iOS will terminate it.

Look at the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/registering-applications-to-run-in-background#application-registration-categories) and ask for permission.

Comment: I've already enabled that and it works in the background. The problem is looping when it is in the background. But I have already implemented a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. When an AVPlayer stops playing, the app is suspended by iOS even with Background Modes enabled. My looping logic is implemented right after the AVPlayer plays the last item so it doesn't get executed in the background.